# Wireless adpater (Intel 8260) disabled in 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

- lshw gives: *-network DISABLED
  description: Wireless interface
  product: Wireless 8260
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
  logical name: wlp1s0
  version: 3a
  serial: 14:ab:c5:d2:48:d0
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-63-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 8000C-36.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  resources: irq:129 memory:e1100000-e1101fff
- lspci gives: 01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
  ]lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 gives Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
  Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
- Firmware apparently installed  (iwlwifi  352256  1 iwlmvm
  cfg80211 778240  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211)
- dkms is installed through synaptic and yet no additional drivers found.
- Kernel is 5.8.0-63-generic.
- No dual boot and secure boot is disabled.

Definitely stuck... Thanks for any help

Comment: DISABLED usually means disabled, either by hardware switch (also a key or key combo) or disabled in UEFI.

Comment: Thank you so much! I unchecked all the "switches" in the BIOS and it is solved. (And I feel stupid)